# To catch someone‘s eye

Tags: phrase-request, english

Wie übersetzt man die Redewendung

> to catch someone‘s eye

oft mit Bedienung bzw. Kellner benützt?

Comment: *ins Auge fallen*, *auffallen*.

Comment: Die Frage lässt sich mühelos mit einem Blick in ein Wörterbuch beantworten.

Comment: Not a bad question, but you should expand it by saying why you think  "oft mit Bedienung bzw. Kellner benützt?" is the right phrase, or even why you fear it might be wrong. That would make the question non-trivial. "Pure" translation requests are frowned upon on this site, but this is a self-worked translation that almost qualifies. Just show a bit more work.

Comment: @johnl: wenn Du keine Mühe hattest, diese Redewendung in einem Wörterbuch zu finden, wäre es hilfreich, dem OP einen Link zu Deinem Wörterbuch zu geben und zu verraten, wie Du unter den dort gegebenen Vorschlägen den Kontext zu Bedienung/Kellner hergestellt hast. **Dasselbe gilt auch für die nachfolgenden Close-Voter**

Comment: @Takkat Das selbstständige Auffinden einer völlig gewöhnlichen Redewendung in einem Wörterbuch ist m.E. zumutbar. Im Übrigen ist nach meiner Überzeugung nicht nach dem Herstellen eines "Kontexts zu Bedienung/Kellner" gefragt, sondern nach der Übersetzung einer englischen Redewendung, für deren Nutzung im Englischen einfach ein Beispiel angeführt wird.

Comment: @johnl: Gäbe es nur einen Eintrag, würde ich Dir Recht geben, aber [mein Wörterbuch](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/to%20catch%20someone%E2%80%98s%20eye) hat hier 3 Einträge, von denen ich als Muttersprachler natürlich weiß, dass nur der dritte Eintrag in Frage kommt. Das kann aber jemand, der gerade Deutsch lernt, nicht. Für Lernende ist die Wahl der richtigen Übersetzung einer englischen Redewendung **im Kontext** eine der Stärken von GL und da unterscheiden wir uns grundlegend von einem Wörterbuch. Wir sollten uns da nicht selbst ein Bein stellen.

Answer (score 2):

Man sagt zwar auf ähnliche Weise "Sie ist mir mit dem blauen Hut ins Auge gefallen", wenn man etwas optisch wahrgenommen hat, aber nicht in Bezug auf Situationen, in denen man die Aufmerksamkeit des Kellners erreichen will.

Da spricht man eher von *sich bemerkbar machen*, oder, wie bereits ausgedrückt, *die Aufmerksamkeit erregen*.

Früher hat man gelegentlich, in weniger feinen Kaschemmen, dem Kellner auch *geschnippst* (mit den Fingern) oder nach ihm *gepfiffen*, also aufs Ohr gezielt.

*Den Kellner heranwinken* ist verbreitet und nicht zwingend mit Armbewegungen verbunden.

Answer (score 2):

*Den Blick von jemandem suchen* wäre die naheliegendste Übersetzung:

> Er wollte zahlen und suchte den Blick des Kellners.